# too many db2ckpw processes using DB2 Express in MAC

Tags: macos, db2

I successfully installed DB2 express on my mac (OSX El Capitan) using the guide at 
 [Installing DB2 on Mac OS El Capitan](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797)  , but I'm seeing a problem when connecting to the database.

Using the db2 command line processor (db2clp), I can connect using my current login id. (e.g. db2 connect to mydb), however, when I connect and specify the connect userid (e.g. db2 connect to mydb user ian) , a new process is spawned (db2ckpw) with every connect request.   This db2 connect is successful, but it creates a new process id with every connection.  Eventually, the OS runs out of processes.

DB2 was installed in my personal account and I have enabled OS authentication by following the installation steps

```
         cd /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security
         sudo chown root /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
         sudo chmod u+rxs /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw 
         sudo chmod o+rx  /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
```

The db2 configuration (db2 get dbm cfg)  is using the defaults and is set for authentication = SERVER.

Not sure what else to check or if this is a known problem with DB2 for the Mac.

Edit:  Database directory is as follows

```
Database 1 entry: 
 Database alias                       = CLOUD210 
 Database name                        = CLOUD210 
 Local database directory             = /Users/igovett 
 Database release level               = f.00 
 Comment                              = 
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect 
 Catalog database partition number    = 0 
 Alternate server hostname            = 
 Alternate server port number         =
```

Comment: How is the database cataloged to which you are connecting (the output of `db2 list db directory`)?

Comment: @mustaccio: This is a local database created by 'db2 create database cloud210

Comment: database directory is as follows <pre> Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = CLOUD210
 Database name                        = CLOUD210
 Local database directory             = /Users/igovett
 Database release level               = f.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
</pre>

Comment: @mustaccio - attempting to fix the above formatting:  Database directory is as follows 

    Database 1 entry:  
    Database alias                         = CLOUD210    
    Database name                        = CLOUD210  
    Local database directory          = /Users/igovett  
    Database release level            = f.00       Comment                              =
    Directory entry type                 = Indirect
    Catalog database partition number    = 0      
    Alternate server hostname            =  
    Alternate server port number         =

Comment: Try cataloging it as a loopback: `db2 catalog tcpip node loopback remote localhost server 50000` (or whatever port you're using) and `db2 catalog db CLOUD210 as CLOUD211 at node loopback`, then connect to CLOUD211.

Comment: FYI, this seems to be a regression of sorts; the problem was supposed to be fixed in version 9.7: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC64708

Comment: @mustaccio , As you suggested, I cataloged the new node, and db using the loopback - restarted the database manager and then  'connect to cloud211'.   Despite these changes, the problem remains.

Regarding the problem which was fixed in 9.7 ,  I think this is a different problem.  Based on the description, there was a failure when authentication = CLIENT but was fixed by switching to authentication = SERVER.  The current problem I'm having is with authentication = SERVER.

Comment: For local connections the `AUTHENTICATION` setting has no effect, so I thought that may be simulating remote connection via loopback might help. I'm afraid I made a mistake in my suggestion: it should have been `db2 catalog db CLOUD210 as CLOUD211 at node loopback authentication server`.

Comment: @mustaccio - I cataloged using 'db2 catalogdb cloud210 as cloud212 at node loopback authentication server', restarted the datatabase manager, but the 'connect to cloud212 user igovett'  still created new db2ckpw processes.   I could trying using db2 9.7 for the Mac to see if an older version would work, but cannot find a link for this version - just 10.1 for the Mac.

Comment: Another note regarding this problem.   I installed db2 as a non-root user.  Not sure if this is a factor with this problem.    The db2chkpw processes are not running as userid=root although the executable file is owned by root (chown root db2chkpw) as specified in the install docs.   Not sure if db2chkpw should be running as root ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 support team has opened a defect for this issue.  A fix should be available in the next release.

For more information, please refer to the post on developerworks at  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797#repliesPg=1.